# 3 Table SQL Query, one line per object

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have to query a database in which **Objects** are in one table, the Attributes of those objects in a 2nd table, and the values of those Attributes are in a 3rd table.  Stupid, I know.

**Table Info (the basics anyway)**

```
OBJECT -- obj_id, name
ATTRIBUTE -- att_id, name
VALUE -- obj_id, att_id, value
```

I want a query in which the attributes of each object occur across the top of my results, and the values of those attributes are filled in for each object.  At first I was thinking a simple 2 inner join query would work, but that will give me a result for each attribute of each object, whereas I want each object to it's own line.

My second thought is that I'm going to have to create a temporary table that basically combines the `OBJECT` and `ATTRIBUTE` table, then `INSERT` the info from the **VALUE** table, and then use the very simple query on my new **temporary** table.

Figured I'd post this on here first to get other thoughts and points of view.

Comment: You probably want to PIVOT the attributes.

Comment: How do these tables relate? It seems you're missing a foreign key.

Comment: I did forget the FKs, sorry....added them up there

Comment: I assume you will only be querying one object at a time since there is no gaurantee that different objects will have the same attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially write a procedure that builds a dynamic SQL string by cursoring through the attribute table. That's about the only way that you could do this without hard-coding the attribute names.

If you don't mind hard-coding the attribute names there are two ways to go about it

Simple subqueries: *(slightly easier to read and understand)*

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    (SELECT value FROM Value v JOIN Attribute a ON v.att_id = a.att_id WHERE a.name = 'Attribute1' and v.obj_id = o.obj_id) [Attribute1],
    (SELECT value FROM Value v JOIN Attribute a ON v.att_id = a.att_id WHERE a.name = 'Attribute2' and v.obj_id = o.obj_id) [Attribute2]
    --etc...
FROM
    [Object] o;
```

Or using PIVOT: *(probably a bit faster)*

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    o.name ObjectName, 
    a.name AttributeName, 
    v.value AttributeValue
FROM
    [Object] o
    JOIN Value v ON v.obj_id = o.obj_id
    JOIN Attribute a ON a.att_id = v.att_id
)
SELECT
    ObjectName,
    [Attribute1],
    [Attribute2]
    --etc
FROM
    CTE
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AttributeValue)
    FOR AttributeName IN ([Attribute1],[Attribute2])
) as Results;
```

In these examples, 'Attribute1' and 'Attribute2' are the attribute names in the name column in the Attribute table.

If you did want to build a dynamic query to handle arbitrary attributes (if you can't hard-code) then you'd still be using one of these approaches as a template for that dynamic query. The PIVOT method would be much simpler to use in that case imo.

Comment: I am able to hard-code.  Tried your your first solution, but keep getting NULL for the result in my subquery.  I just noticed I hosed my table examples above.  The OBJECT and the ATTRIBUTE tables are actually linked by the VALUE table.  Where the PKs for OBJECT and ATTRIBUTE are used as multiple PKs in the VALUE table.  I will edit the original question...that might make my solution easier

Comment: The good news is that data model makes a heck of a lot more sense now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm still getting NULL for the result of the subquery, not sure what the problem is yet.  I basically copied your example.

Comment: Take the subquery out and run it on its own. You'll need to stuff in a valid obj_id. Be aware of any extra spaces in the Attribute.Name field and the spelling of the attribute name including case if your DB collation is case sensitive.

Comment: Noob error.  The attribute I picked to run a test happened to actually be NULL.  I will try out the PIVOT method later and test speed.  Thanks for your help, this was what I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help. Folks would probably say the `PIVOT` method is more elegant or easier for the query optimizer and they'd be right, but in practice unless you're working with a whole lot of data or lots of traffic the subqueries will probably perform just fine.

Comment: This is for an extract/load project.  So once things are extracted the SQL will basically be thrown away.